# Mapping 2 columns in pandas to third one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda

I want to create pandas column `'Link'` based on other 2 columns (`URL` and `Title`) in order to create column which will hold HTML link tag with title in form:

`<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(df['Ad_URL'],df['Title'])`

I'm using:

```
def Ad_Link(df):
    return ('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(df['Ad_URL'],df['Title']))

df['Link'] = df[['Ad_URL','Title']].apply(lambda x:Ad_Link(x), axis=1)
```

but it doesn't work as expected.

It gives: 
`<a href="List of all URLs">List of all Titles</a>` for all items in  df['Link']

It suppose iterate and give:

```
<a href="URL[0]">Title[0]</a> 
<a href="URL[1]">Title[1]</a>
```

**EDIT**

Actually my solution worked, had a problem with data frame initially.

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: are you getting error?

Comment: update your question with expected output and actual output

Comment: can you please explain how its doesn't work as expected. for you????

Comment: I've added current and expected output

Comment: can you change the parameter name `df` into the function `Add_Link` to something else?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar was thinking same, change variable name for your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your code working for me nice. But added multiple solutions with same output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ad_URL':['u1', 'u2', 'u3'], 'Title':['t1', 't2', 't3']})


def Ad_Link(df):
    return ('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(df['Ad_URL'],df['Title']))

df['Link'] = df[['Ad_URL','Title']].apply(lambda x:Ad_Link(x), axis=1)

#change variable in function to x
def Ad_Link1(x):
    return ('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(x['Ad_URL'],x['Title']))

df['Link1'] = df[['Ad_URL','Title']].apply(lambda x:Ad_Link1(x), axis=1)

#removed lambda function
def Ad_Link2(x):
    return ('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(x['Ad_URL'],x['Title']))

df['Link2'] = df.apply(Ad_Link2, axis=1)

#pass columns names to lambda function, changed function
def Ad_Link3(url, link):
    return ('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(url, link))

df['Link3'] = df.apply(lambda x: Ad_Link3(x['Ad_URL'],x['Title']), axis=1)

#only lambda function solution
df['Link4'] = df.apply(lambda x: '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(x['Ad_URL'], x['Title']), axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
  Ad_URL Title                 Link                Link1                Link2  \
0     u1    t1  <a href="u1">t1</a>  <a href="u1">t1</a>  <a href="u1">t1</a>   
1     u2    t2  <a href="u2">t2</a>  <a href="u2">t2</a>  <a href="u2">t2</a>   
2     u3    t3  <a href="u3">t3</a>  <a href="u3">t3</a>  <a href="u3">t3</a>   

                 Link3                Link4  
0  <a href="u1">t1</a>  <a href="u1">t1</a>  
1  <a href="u2">t2</a>  <a href="u2">t2</a>  
2  <a href="u3">t3</a>  <a href="u3">t3</a>
```

Comment: Under #removed lambda function should be Ad_Link2 in df['Link2'] = df.apply(Ad_Link1, axis=1)?

Comment: @Harvey - oops, typo, there should be `df['Link2'] = df.apply(Ad_Link2, axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ad_URL':['u1', 'u2', 'u3'], 'Title':['t1', 't2', 't3']})

def Ad_Link(df):
    return ('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(df['Ad_URL'],df['Title']))

df['Link'] = df[['Ad_URL','Title']].apply(lambda x:Ad_Link(x), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Ad_URL Title                 Link
0     u1    t1  <a href="u1">t1</a>
1     u2    t2  <a href="u2">t2</a>
2     u3    t3  <a href="u3">t3</a>
```